# last selected cell state is true after modifying tableview frame

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Unexpected behaviour here.
I have a chat composed of a tableview and a bottom bar with a textView.
When the user select the textView the keyboard appears.

I use the notification `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` to modify the frame of the tableview.

Selecting a row display a `UIAlertController` with different actions removing the keyboard.

This `UIAlertController` has a cancel action which is removing the selection of the cell (by selection i mean the grey style appearing when the selected state of the cell is true).
The selection is removed by setting `cell.selected` to false.

Problem is, when the keyboard appears, this previously selected cell is selected again, i tried to loop through the cells to put them all at selected false but depending on where the cell is located, the selected state will only appear after scrolling, making my loop uneffective.

Since i don't select the cells manually in my code, i assume this is a behaviour resulting maybe from the change of frame?
Is there something i can do to fix this?

Comment: share some code .

Comment: can't, you would need at least half the controller code meaning 250 lines, the model and the storyboard to reproduce and i am under nda.
Just trying to see if someone encountered this issue before, otherwise i will just filled a radar and move on

Comment: [How to - Example Code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I don't need a how to, thank you

Comment: The question covers all you need to answer it. Code is not required, guys :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an indexPath variable for referring to it later

```
var indexPath: IndexPath?
```

Inside tableView delegate didSelect Row assign the selected indexPath to the one you have created

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.indexPath = indexPath
}
```

Inside the function where you're listening for keyboard notification deselect the selected row using your referenced indexPath

```
func keyboardDidShow(notification: Notification) {
    // your existing code...
    if let indexPath = indexPath {
       // deselect the selected row. I set animation to false
       tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)

       // just a clean up set the indexPath to nil once done
       self.indexPath = nil
    }
}
```

This was a one way to fix the problem.

Each Cell has a selectedView you can set that Views backgroundColor to clearColor then the row will be selected but you won't see that. or you can return your own view for the selectedBackgroundView.

Comment: It seems that setting the selected state to false wasn't enough and indeed using deselectRowAtIndexPath solved my issue.
Weird but that was the way to go, thanks for the hint
(just had to set this where i used to the selected state)

Still seems like a bug to me though, what is the point to have a selected state if using it leads to unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a bit of code will help a lot.
With limited info, this is what I feel:

It may be due to reuse of a dequeued cell (since you make changes to the table when the keyboard notification is triggered).

This is my general practice:

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: CELL_REUSE_IDENTIFIER)
prepareDequeuedCellForReuse(cell)
```

The prepareDequeuedCellForReuse has something like this:

```
private func prepareDequeuedCellForReuse(_ dequedCell: UITableViewCell){
    dequedCell.textLabel?.text = ""
    dequedCell.tag = -1;
    dequedCell.isSelected = false
}
```

I recommend you clear the selection here.

Comment: was due to me using cell.selected = false instead of using deselectRowAtIndexPath.
I don't get why the setter isn't private is using it leads to unexpected behaviour but at least my issue is solved, thanks for your time though.